# Cordova iOS iPhone X - Home indicator - Edge protection - DeferringSystemGestures?

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, gesture, iphone-x

I'm working on a webapp built with Cordova for both iOS and Android. Everything was fine until I launched tests on the new Apple's iPhoneX. As you may know, Apple decided to remove the physical home button by replacing it by a home indicator at the bottom of the screen:

[image: iPhoneX home indicator at screen bottom]

This home indicator is always visible on your screen and it goes over your webapp content. When user want to navigate between apps or to go back to the home screen, he has to swip up this home indicator (which is very sensitive). This wonderful invention brought to my webapp 2 main problems:

1. This break my webapp design because it goes over the content.
2. The system gesture enter in conflict with my webapp gesture. My entire gameplay is based on drag & drop and all draggable icon are at the bottom of the screen, under the home indicator.

#### 1. How to hide the home indicator?

To solve the first point I found a plugin called [cordova-plugin-hide-home-indicator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-hide-home-indicator). This will hide (with fadeIn/Out effect) the home indicator after a few second of inactivity. But every times a touchscreen event is detected, the home button is visible again... I have red [here](https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/iphone-x-dealing-with-home-indicator-2e8e47f5647f) that even if the Objective C (Xcode) function **prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden()** (which I guess is used by this Cordova plugin) return **true** it doesn't mean that the home indicator will be hidden for ever. Well... if somebody has a better solution I would appreciate your help!

#### 2. How to lock system gesture?

I found a Xcode function called **[preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887512-preferredscreenedgesdeferringsys?language=objc)** They explain that normally the system will always take precedence on an app gesture, but in some cases (for immersive games for exemple) you can ask for your app to take precedence on the system. This sounds great! But unfortunately I don't know anything of Objective C :) I didn't find any plugin about that point.

In this [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/801) from Apple at 10:33, they talk about **edge protection**, which should do the trick by giving the app gesture the precedence, but again, I didn't find any plugin for Cordova...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't hide the home indicator. The solution by Apple is to use the new CSS constants as padding for the safe areas of the device. Read this to get starting point: [iPhone X support](https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/)

Comment: Yes you are right about the point #1. I have read this too and I'm not going to try to hide the home indicator. But what about the point #2? I have seen some games (eg: earthtone) using the preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() function. By this way, the first time he user swipe up home indicator, you will see it going up and light up, but this won't bring you back to the home screen. It's only the second time your do this gesture that you will quit the game. So the app gesture can take the precedence on the system gesture. Any clue about how to do it in a Cordova App? Thanks!

Comment: You're right about that API. To use gesture protection for swiping from the bottom edge you're right about that API. But to make use of it within Cordova you will need to make a plugin to interface with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will read more about creating plugin on Cordova. But without knowledges in Objectives-C, it's going to be difficult :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin in order to avoid edge gestures at iOS

https://github.com/distinctdan/cordova-plugin-screen-edges

It's very easy to use, i used in a cordova project and it works as expected